# scrolldepth.js and scrollto.js don't seem to work on same page

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, scrollto

I've made a a website with a one page layout and use the scrollto() function to allow the users to click in the menu and the webpage smoothly scrolls to the section on the webpage.

Now I want to track the users who don't use the menu and just scroll down the webpage without using the menu.

When I add the scrolldepth() function to the webpage, scrollto() doesn't work anymore. Nothing happens when you click in the menu.

I already tried with noConflict() to make it work since there are two versions of jquery on the page to make scrolldepth() work. This seem to make scrollto() work again but doesn't track the page in google analytics.

Did anybody encounter the same issues before and how did you solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not include jQuery twice on the same page. 
This is very probably what is causing your error.

Comment: I tried that but it still no result, must be something in the scrollto() that conflicts with scrolldepth()

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code. Can you make a fiddle or post a link?